# matlab: how to concatenate strings?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, avi

I want to produce multiple movies in matlab like

```
for i=1:5
   %calculate a movie-array H (gridsize depends on i)
   number=num2str(i);
   movie2avi(H, 'movie_'+number+'.avi');
end
```

Obviously it doesn't work and I found nothing about multiple movie production in matlab.
Any idea how to vary the filename in this command to produce different movie-files instead of overwrite one file?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - you **must** be more specific. What is the error you got?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In matlab you concatenate strings using [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) and **not** using `+` operator!

Try

```
movie2avi( H, strcat('movie_', number, '.avi') );
```

Alternatively, you can use `[]` to concat the literals into a string

```
movie2avi( H, ['movie_', number, '.avi'] );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect, though my question wasn't that precise ;)